# set max and min value in lightning-input-field like we do in lightning-input

Tags: lightning-web-components

`<lightning-input-field field-name="Date_of_Joining__c" onchange={handleFieldChange}>
 </lightning-input-field>`
this is tag where i want to put min and max value for my date

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set `min` and `max` for `lightning-input-field` like that of `lightning-input`. You should implement the logic in change handler.

As you want to validate dates, you will require to create [javasript date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and compare it with selected date.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {

    handleFieldChange(event) {
        let selected = new Date(event.target.value);
        let max = new Date(2019, 7, 30);  // 30 Aug 2019 (month is 0 index based)
        let min = new Date(2019, 7, 1); // 1 Aug 2019
        if (selected > max || selected < min)
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Enter valid date',
                variant: 'error',
                message: `Date should be between ${min.toDateString()} and ${max.toDateString()}`,
            }));
    }
}
```